# How to get api name in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a angular directive

```
mainApplicationModule
    .directive('usSpinner2', ['$http', '$rootScope','$location','$state', function($http, $rootScope,$location,$state) {
        return {
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
                $rootScope.spinnerActive = false;

                scope.isLoading = function() {
                    return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
                };
                scope.$watch(scope.isLoading, function(loading) {
                    $rootScope.spinnerActive = loading;
                    if (loading) {
                        elm.removeClass('ng-hide');
                    } else {
                        elm.addClass('ng-hide');
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    }])
```

when I request on server using $http service the spinner starts and it stops when response is arrived on client side.

I am using $http service like this on client side

```
$http.get(baseUrl+'filename/apiname').success(function(res,req){
  //code
})
```

at server side filename.js

```
router.get('/apiname',function(req,res){
  //code
})
```

I want to get the current apiname which is requesting data on server in the directive above. I could not find an answer after searching for hours. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the definition of `pending requests`

**PendingRequest:**

**Array of config objects** for currently pending requests. This is primarily meant to be used for debugging purposes.

So. `$http.pendingRequests` returns an array of config objects,

So you can try

`$http.pendingRequests[0].url` to get the current api url.

You can try something like this.

```
$scope.isLoading = function() {
     return $http.pendingRequests.length > 0;
 };


 $scope.$watch($scope.isLoading, function(loading) {
      if (loading) {
         console.log($http.pendingRequests[0].url)
      } else {
         console.log($http.pendingRequests)
      }
 });
```

[Here is a DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/pIff1iwNnB7qzcFfajvd?p=preview)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work I am getting error can not read property 'url' of undefined

Comment: Please paste your latest code once. Check the demo link. Open the console and make a JSON request and click on fetch.

Comment: Sorry I pasted the main line at wrong place. It worked. Thanks